# Stopping infinite service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, infinite-loop

I am making an app which consists of an infinite running service which needs to be stopped when the checkbox is disabled.
i am currently inheriting intentservice class for Myservice class but the problem is it doesn't gets stopped on clicking the buttons(which calls stopservice) and keeps running, i have tried logging and ondestroy() does gets called but service doesn't stop.
i have Also tried inheriting service class but still same. i am posting the code below.
From MainActivity:`service.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Myservice.class);
            if(sp==false)
            { Log.d("service1", "Startservice invoked");
                startService(intent);
            sp=true;
            }
            else if(sp==true)
                { 
                Log.d("service1", "Stopservice invoked");
                stopService(intent);
                sp=false;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });`
```

sp is just a static flag to check whether the checkbox was clicked with initial value as false.(isenabled() method was giving problems)
Myservice code:

```
    public class Myservice extends IntentService {

public Myservice() {
    super("My Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     while(true){
         Log.d("service1", "Service is running");
         try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }}}
```

I know why all this is happening(onhandleintent runs on a seperate thread). But is there any way to stop the infinite thread/loop on preference change?

Comment: The reason it's not stopping is because of the while loop. You could add a global boolean flag mIsRunning and set it to true in the onCreate of the service. You then need to change your while loop to: while(true && mIsRunning). You must then override the IntentService onDestroy method and set mIsRunning = false. That will cause the loop to stop when the service is destroyed.

Comment: thanks, it worked, i can't beleive the solurion was so simple.